# XamarinForms: StackLayout inside RelativeLayout is not filling the whole screen

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this:

```
<RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0,15" Spacing="10"></StackLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But for some reason, even tough the RelativeLayout clearly expands, the StackLayout doesn't. How can I get the StackLayout to stretch horizontally and fill the whole width/height of the screen?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For RelativeLayout you will need to use constraints instead of Vertical/Horizontal options.
Should be something like

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0,15" Spacing="10"
     RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                Property=Width,
                                Factor=1}"
     RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                Property=Height,
                                Factor=1}">
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, and this answer doesnt seem to work on android. seems to be common for other child controls such as grid as well